# Replicate only specific records of a table

Tags: sql-server, replication, merge-replication

I have setup a merge replication and have got a new requirement:
The records of a table should not be replicated until the [state] column is changed from 0 to 1. I have created a filter for the replication to limit replication to records with state = 1, but now the records are removed from the subscriber when the state is set to 0. 
Is it possible to keep those records on the subscriber?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not with the technology you use - this is not what replication is intended to do. A filter is indeed an active filter, also removing objects. You CAN add a specific field for that that you never reset.

Answer (score 1):

for replicating an specific set of data, you can create a view and replicate it.

[here you can see what data you can publish](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152559(v=sql.120).aspx)

there is a small detail though:

> All types of replication allow you to replicate views. The view (and
>   its accompanying index, if it is an indexed view) can be copied to the
>   Subscriber, but the base table must also be replicated.
>
> For indexed views, transactional replication also allows you to
>   replicate the indexed view as a table rather than a view, eliminating
>   the need to also replicate the base table. To do this, specify one of
>   the "indexed view logbased" options for the @type parameter of
>   [sp_addarticle (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173857(v=sql.120).aspx). For more information about using
>   [sp_addarticle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173857(v=sql.120).aspx), see [Define an Article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146887(v=sql.120).aspx).

[image]